# why is my <Fade> property from react-awesome-reveal overlapping all the layers in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, animation, scroll

when I remove the "<Fade>" code functions normally, but when I add <Fade> it overlaps all the layers and becomes the top layer in all the situations even though it's inside a <div> which works fine. I have tried the z-1 and z-10 but it still does not work.

```
import React from "react";
import { Fade } from "react-awesome-reveal";

export const About = () => {
  return (
    <div name="about" className="w-full h-screen bg-[#124559] text-gray-300">
      <div className="flex px-14 flex-col justify-center items-center w-full h-full">
        <div className="max-w-[1000px] w-full grid grid-cols-2 gap-8">
          <div className="sm:text-right pb-8 pl-4">
            <p className="text-4xl font-bold inline border-b-4 border-pink-600">
              About
            </p>
          </div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-[1000px] w-full grid sm:grid-cols-2 gap-8 px-4">
          <div className="sm:text-right text-4xl font-bold">
            <Fade direction="left">  --> HERE
              <p>Get to know me:</p>
            </Fade>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Fade>
              <p>
                I'm a computer major
              </p>
            </Fade>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default About;
```